# Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in Restlet

Tags: restlet

So I'm trying to set up CORS on Restlet 2.3.0 using [CorsFilter](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jse/engine/org/restlet/engine/application/CorsFilter.html). Unfortunately there I can't seem to find a way to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` so that I can add, say, `POST, GET, OPTIONS`.

The problem is that without this I keep getting 405 errors, eg:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just set this up successfully for my work and I did not have to add that the header `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`. I think you need to use that if you want to restrict the allowed methods for cross-domain access. I followed the exact same code as mentioned in your link:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot()
{
  // Create a Restlet router that defines routes
  final Router router = new Router(getContext());

  // Add a CORS filter to allow cross-domain requests
  CorsFilter corsFilter = new CorsFilter(getContext(), router);
  corsFilter.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("*")));
  corsFilter.setAllowedCredentials(true);

  // Setup up resource routing
  // ...

  return corsFilter;  // Important!
}
```

Comment: Goodness me, I must've been asleep! I missed the `return corsFilter` bit!

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what bit me as well. Hence the "Important!" comment in the code above :-)